# Alpine.js How to get array from $store?

Tags: alpine.js

How to read products array on getSales, for others uses?

```js
document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
  Alpine.store("getProducts", {
    url: "http://localhost:3000/products",
    products: [],
    getAllProducts() {
      fetch(this.url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => (this.products = data));
    },
  });
});


const getSales = () => ({
  products: $store.getProducts.products
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Alpine.store()` global function](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store#accessing%20stores) to access the store object externally:

```
document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
  Alpine.store('getProducts').getAllProducts()

  const getSales = () => ({
    products: Alpine.store('getProducts').products
  })

  console.log([...getSales().products])
});
```

Comment: Initially products is empty, how to execute getAllProducts before and populate products array?

Comment: Using the same syntax you can access methods of the store object as well. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Dauros

This dont return the data, return empty array.

```js
Proxy {}
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Array(0)
    length: 0
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
  [[IsRevoked]]: false
```